# WCF Hosting on remote server

Tags: wcf, hosting

I created a WCF service at my machine, I hosted it under IIS, it works fine.
then I compile my service , and i put the compile code at remote server. i hosted it under IIS on remote server. but when i try to consume it in my client at my own machine it generate the following error.

The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '

then I try to open it at remote server using browser. when i click on the link for wsdl it says bad request or invalid host name. what could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The "content type" error is actually produced on the client side because IIS is sending an HTML response to your soap request. The cause is usually the virtual directory in IIS isn't properly configured or that WCF is failing to initialize. The contents of the IIS response can sometimes be really helpful in debugging these issues. To inspect that HTML, use a tool like Fiddler to intercept and review the HTTP traffic during your request.

If the intercepted HTTP traffic isn't helpful, then start troubleshooting IIS by creating a simple HTML only page (something like test.html) in the folder where the WCF service .svc file is located. Try acessing that page through the browser. If the browser correctly shows the page contents then IIS is working and the problem is in the WCF config. Based on your two errors, I'd say you have an IIS config issue in the virtual directory for the service.